# Random Forest training ROC score monotonically increasing with max_depth

Tags: classification, random-forest, overfitting

[image]

Using GridSearchCV always picks the max_depth the highest number supplied to it as the best estimator. The gap between the cross validation score and the train score keeps increasing. Is this RF overfitting? How can I tackle this?

Comment: No, it is not overfitting.  Overfitting is when increasing the model complexity worsens the hold out (in your case, cross validation) error.

Comment: So, should I keep testing with greater values of max_depth?

Comment: Yes, until the CV error starts to increase.